# How to extract the value of an input field through getAttribute() or executeScript() method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

There is input field which id is condition and `getText()` and `getAttribute()` are not working

```
driver.findElement(By.id("condition")).getText() //is not working..
```

So I tried in the console

```
document.getElementById("condition").value //return the value.
```

So I tried

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
System.out.println(jse.executeScript("document.getElementById(condition).value");
String value = jse.executeScript("document.getElementById(condition).value").toString();
AssertVerify(value, "15");
```

Getting following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

How to get use the javascript to get the value and assign to other variable.

Comment: It should be `"document.getElementById('condition').value"`, with apostrophes around `condition`.

Comment: How did you try `getAttribute()`? `getAttribute("value")` should have worked.

Comment: As @Guy said, for input text box, you have to use `getAttribute("value")` to read typed string in it.  for other controls, you should use `getText()` which can only fetch readonly text of control.  No need to use `executeScript` for you case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code trial was near perfect. You need to pass the `id` attribute of the element within single quotes i.e. **`'...'`** as follows:

```
String value = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('condition').value").toString();
```

---

### Update

As you are still unable to retrieve the *value* through `executeScript()` method, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Use `getAttribute()` to retrieve the text:

  ```
  String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("condition"))).getAttribute("value");
  ```
- Use `executeScript` to retrieve the text:

  ```
  WebElement myElem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("condition")));
  String value = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('condition').value").toString();
  ```

Comment: added single for element id but returns null but when running in console it returns the value.

Comment: Trying the 2nd one.. first one is not working as i already mentioned

Comment: Try out the updated answer and let me know the status.